# Unable to set html data of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to display an external poll(inject a) script within a div using the jquery html() method. I've also tried using the .append method instead of .html but same result.

This is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/6S3zg/1/

The script is not being displayed within the div. Within Chrome I receive the error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null "

```
<div id="toupdate">

</div>​

var htmlString = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\" src=\"http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js\"><\/script>\
    <noscript><a href=\"http://polldaddy.com/poll/6343621/\">New Poll</a><\/noscript>";

$("#toupdate").html(htmlString); 

alert(htmlString);
```

​

Comment: are you trying to inject a script into the page? If so, this isn't how you'd want to go about it.

Comment: @jackwanders yes im trying to inject a script

Comment: @jackwanders ive tried using .append method but same result

Comment: can you not use iFrame instead of div and write script tag and link into it? and make visible 'true/false' iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was the script. I needed to wait for the pages to load until setting its html content. Error is no longer thrown but content is still not set.

http://jsfiddle.net/6S3zg/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in a local html file. Works fine, might be JS Fiddle. Don't forget to include jquery. I also reformatted your htmlstring value, you don't need to escape each \ or " in your case just make the string literal by using ' and ending with a '

```
<div id="toupdate">

</div>​

var htmlString = '<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>

<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6343621/">New Poll</a></noscript>";

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#toupdate").html(htmlString); 

alert(htmlString);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but I don't understand how this is working. You seem to be mixing jQuery code outside of the <script> tag, is this even possible ?